# Creating Bezier curves that meet curvature condition

Tags: python, calculation, bezier

[enter image description here][1]As part of a homework assignment, Im trying to create bezier curves (with 4 points) with a maximum finite curvature of K_x. Curvature is calculated with a defined formula k = |y''|/(1+y'^2)^1.5

FOr a set of 4 points where p0=(0,0) and p3=(0.3,0) and p1,p2 are the degree of freedom.

What I tried is to take the space of the square between [(0,0), (0,0.15), (0.3,0.15), (0,-0.15)] and scan it such that for every point p1 I pick (which because of symmetry I choose it only to be in the top right quarter) I scan all possible p2 and for each option I check whether the curve meets the condition of the curvature and if so I save the points that meet the condition.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def bezzier_curve(p0, p1, p2, p3, t):
    b0 = b_in_calc(3, 0, t) * np.transpose(p0)
    b1 = b_in_calc(3, 1, t) * np.transpose(p1)
    b2 = b_in_calc(3, 2, t) * np.transpose(p2)
    b3 = b_in_calc(3, 3, t) * np.transpose(p3)
    b = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3
    return b


def b_in_calc(n, i, t):
    b = sc.special.binom(n, i)
    t1 = np.power(1-t, n-i)
    t2 = np.power(t, i)
    return b*t1*t2


def numerical_deriv(y, x):
    # finding numerical derivative of the finction
    dx = np.gradient(x)
    dy = np.gradient(y)
    d = dy/dx
    return d


k_max_allowed = 5
d = 0.3
p0 = np.zeros([1, 2])
p3 = np.array([[0.3, 0]])
p1 = np.zeros([1, 2])
p2 = np.zeros([1, 2])
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000)
P1_space = np.linspace(0, d/2, num=40)
P2_xspace = np.linspace(0, d, endpoint=False, num=40)
P2_yspace = np.linspace(-d/2, d/2, 40)

output_name = 'desired_coordinates_K_max_5.txt'

condition = 0 # if we started writing P1 or not
condition1 = 0 # if we already wrote at least 1 P2 point

with open(output_name, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in range(1, len(P1_space)):
        p1[0, 0] = P1_space[i]
        for j in range(1, len(P1_space)):
            p1[0, 1] = P1_space[j]            
            
            for n in range(1, len(P2_xspace)):
                p2[0,0] = P2_xspace[n]
                for m in range(len(P2_yspace)):
                    p2[0,1] = P2_yspace[m]
                        
                    # create bezier curve
                    bezz = bezzier_curve(p0, p1, p2, p3, t)
                    x_vec = bezz[0, :]
                    y_vec = bezz[1, :]
                        
                    #fig=plt.figure(1,figsize=(6,6))
                    #ax=plt.subplot(111);
                    #plt.plot(x_vec, y_vec)
                        
                    # interpolate points to spread them
                    x_interp = np.linspace(0, d, len(t), endpoint=True)
                    y_interp = np.interp(x_interp, x_vec, y_vec)  
                        
                    # derive and find curvature vector and max k
                    y_deriv = numerical_deriv(y_interp, x_interp)
                    y_deriv2 = numerical_deriv(y_deriv, x_interp)
                    k_vec = y_deriv2/(1 + y_deriv**2)**1.5
                    k_max = np.amax(k_vec)
                        
                    # check if meets condition, if so write it to .txt file
                    if k_max <= k_max_allowed:
                        if condition == 0:
                            f.write('P1:' + str(P1_space[int(i)]) + ',' + str(P1_space[int(j)]) + '\n')
                            condition = 1
                        if condition1 ==0:
                            f.write('P2:')
                            condition1 = 1
                        f.write(str(P2_xspace[n]) + ',' + str(P2_yspace[m]) + '|')
                        
            condition = 0
            condition1 = 0
        f.write('\n')
f.close()

plt.text(5,5 , 'Complete', fontsize = 22)
plt.xlim(0, 15)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

My problem is when I read the file and try a quite a few points, I see that some of the points give curves with higher curvature then K_max I desired. I'd appreciate an advice on what conditions/constrains to add in order to fix this. maybe I should limit the space from which I can pick p2?

I would appreciate an answer with the numerical derivative because as I interpret the results I also use numerical derivative

I want to be able to make sure that the maximal curvature is less then K_max. I use a numerical derivation but the result didn't change when I did analytical derivation for the curve

Edit:
The problem can be seen in the image I've added - where the control points marked in 'x' are causing a curve with large curvature near the left side.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNeeF.png

Comment: Note that that's not the actual formula for curvature. [The actual curvature](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curvature.html) of a 2D parametric function is computed using `κ = (x'y'' - x''y') / (x'x' + y'y')^(3/2)` (where `x` and `y` in this case are shorthand for the `Bx(t)` and `By(t)` functions). So you might be trying to constrain your curve, but you need to constrain the curve, but not on "curvature", it's just "some constraint relation". But, since the problem you're having is with the math (not really the programming of that math)  you're probably going to get more insight on [math.se]

Comment: yeah but since I'm trying to implement this in the code and I cant make out a reasonable result despite using the relation (which is correct in itself) I thought the problem is with the code